# Difference between "however" and "whereas"?

Tags: grammaticality, difference, usage, commas

What is the difference between *however* and *whereas*?

> Cooking is hard, whereas eating is easy.

Can I use *however* in that sentence (instead of *whereas*) or not? If not, why?

The *meaning* of the two words seems very much the same: they both show a contrast between two things. I am confused about how and when to use them in sentences.

Answer (score 6):

However you look at this question it's not easy to answer

Whereas ignoring it is the easy option

However, neither will keep me awake at night

---

I'd always use "whereas" as the second part of a comparison.  "however" could also be used in this way.  Often "however" would have a comma after it when used as the second part of a comparison.

I take "however" as something like "how ever you take the meaning of this" .
OTOH "whereas" is something like "in contrast to the previous opinion"

Answer (score 4):

> Cooking is hard, whereas eating is easy.

*Whereas* is a conjunction used to compare the difference between two things. It is most commonly used to mean "although" or "while in contrast" and could introduce a dependent clause.

In the closest definition to whereas, *however* is a [conjunctive adverb](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/adverbs/con-adverb.html) used to contrast two independent clauses. You wouldn't use it with a dependent clause in this sense.

I would use "however" instead of "whereas" in your example sentence.

> Cooking is hard; However, eating is easy.

The choice of punctuation before "however" depends on which style guide you're using. Many recommend using the semicolon, but it isn't incorrect to use a period. You would not use a comma after a conjunction like "whereas", but you should use it after a conjunctive adverb like "however".

You would not use "whereas" in this sentence, because you aren't showing a direct difference between two facts.

> We thought she was going to come to the party, however, she didn't show up.

If you wanted to use "whereas" in a similar sentence, you would need to compare what we thought with what someone else thought.

> We thought she was going to come to the party, whereas they were certain she wouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

"Whereas" is used in the prefaces to laws.  In this context, "whereas" does not mean "contrary to what was said previously".

Comment: "Whereas" has other meanings too.

Comment: @TRomano -- Indeed.

Comment: @wrod — You made a good-faith edit.  I rejected it, so I owe you an explanation.  Your edit provided well-sourced positive definitions for whereas in a legal context.  Please consider posting them as an answer; I would upvote that answer.  But I chose to not include a positive definition in my answer, because I have seen many uses of "whereas" in this legal context that I think are logically invalid.

Answer (score 2):

The word "however" often is used to caution the listener *Don't get the wrong idea from what I've just said*:

> Of course you can go outdoors! However, you'll need to wear your overcoat.

"Whereas"  cannot introduce such a cautionary remark in respect to the listener's understanding of the first clause in the pair:

> Of course you can go outdoors! Whereas <sup>Wrong</sup> you'll need to wear your overcoat.